# Vertical Navigation Bars

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I am working on a website. I have the main content of the website in the middle, and to the left of the main content I want a vertical navigation bar which contains different links on the website. I know how to create a navbar and style it, but I just don't know how I could do this without the navigation bar interfering with the rest of the website content, here is an example:

https://gyazo.com/8f8fc2f7e57e9b419671e6fda603546c

as you can see in the link, the content of the navigation bar is above the rest of the main content, so, I decided to add float:left; to the stylesheet and I ended up with it being in-line with the main content, except it is now horizontal, not vertical. Why do websites do this? How can you seperate different elements of a webpage and freely move them around without them interfering with other things?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h49bz0LL/)

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSGOMarble</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Coin Flip</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #999999;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin-top: 50px
}
h1 {
background-color: black;
color:white;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: 275px;
margin-right: 275px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.container{
margin-left: 275px;
margin-right: 275px;

}

li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: You need to have separate divisions for nav and any other objects you wish to display. What you have is only the beginnings of a web page. Over time create more styling 'classes' so you do not need so much css code on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float: left` will put all nav items next to each other (as long as there is horizontal space). For a vertical menu just use `display: block`on the `li` items (which is the default, so you don't have to write it in the CSS at all). This will place them below each other.

To fix an element in the window (like your left part with the menu), use `position: fixed`on it - this is relative to the screen, so it won't scroll with the rest. But it will overlap (by default) other non-fixed elements like the main content , so you have to place those with an offset (for example `position: relative; left: 180px;`)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, however, when I fix the list horizontally, all of the content is overlapped as you said, and using position doesn't fix it!

Comment: you have to put it in a separate DIV

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
li {float: left;}
```

and add instead

```
.navbar{float: left}
```

...will solve your problem

but i guess your just missing some basic understanding about layouts and about the positioning of html elements, to freely "move" your elements you just need a layout were things fit for your needs, and then they will not interfer other things :)

Layout tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp
Positioning tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp